# I am having difficulty receiving a user's current location with Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, coordinates, core-location

I have been surfing the web for methods to get a user's current location in Swift 2.0, Unfortunately none have work. Here is the code I have been working on, but it cannot work. I have been playing with the info.plist file but don't know what to add? Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    findMyLocation()
}



func findMyLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

 }

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    for location in locations {
        print("THIS IS THE LATTITUDE \(location.coordinate.latitude)")
    }


    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
}
```

Comment: Just curious,  why would you make the CLLocationManagerDelegate an extension on ViewController?

Comment: Do you call `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled` to determine if your device is even capable of getting location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: in your `didUpdateLocations` function don't force `stopUpdatingLocation`. This function is called multiple times before your location is finalized to be shown on the map. Remove that line and you'll see that your console will print 3-5 times with your lat and long.

The recommended way to get the user location is to always check to make sure you have the permission so that if you don't you can alert the user and ask for said permission.

In your viewDidLoad()

```
locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

// .AuthorizedInUse or .AuthorizedAlways depending on your app
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedInUse {
        locationManager?.distanceFilter = 5.0
        locationManager?.requestLocation()
    }
```

This ensures that you're requesting authorization if there is none and checking if they declined. In addition utilize this function in your `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
{
    //Again this can be .AuthorizedAlways or .AuthorizedInUse depending
    if status == .AuthorizedAlways {
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        // ...
    }
}
```

This allows the app to respond properly if they change the location permissions in the middle of using your location services after the `viewDidLoad()`.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations.last
    centerLocation = location

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))
    userLocationRegion = region
    mainMapView.showAnnotations(mainMapView.annotations, animated: true)

    self.mainMapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code in full, I got lost in your edit instructions. And I also deleted the stopUpdatingLocation function and I got a big console error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or/and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription depends on your use case